# PropertyName in FluentValidation child validators

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I'm trying something a little odd in FluentValidation and I can't quite seem to make it work. The model I'm validating has strings in it and I would like run validations on the objects they parse to, for example, that a date serialized as a string is before right now, like so:

```
RuleFor(x => x.SentDateString).AsDate(d => d.DateInPast());
```

I recognize that the normal way to do that is make the model itself contain the parsed dates and other objects and then validate the deserialized data, but I have my reasons for wanting to do it this way.

I have this working like this:

```
// general mechanism for adding "casting" rules
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TFrom> Xform<T, TFrom, TTo>(
    this IRuleBuilder<T, TFrom> ruleBuilder,
     Func<TFrom, TTo> xform,
     Func<IRuleBuilder<TFrom, TTo>, IRuleBuilderOptions<TFrom, TTo>> innerRules)
{
    var innerValidator = new InlineValidator<TFrom>() {
        v => innerRules(v.RuleFor(x => xform(x)))
    };
    return ruleBuilder.SetValidator(innerValidator);
}

// specific rule for making a date
public static IRuleBuilder<T, string> AsDate<T>(
    this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder,
    Func<IRuleBuilder<string, DateTime>, IRuleBuilderOptions<string, DateTime>> innerRules)
{
    Func<string, DateTime> parseDate = (s) =>
    {
        DateTime d;
        DateTime.TryParse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out d);
        return d;
    };
    return Xform(ruleBuilder, parseDate, innerRules);
}

// inner rule used in validating the date object
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, DateTime> DateInPast<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, DateTime> ruleBuilder) =>
    ruleBuilder.LessThan(DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)))
        .WithMessage("{PropertyName} must be in the past");
```

This does validate the property! However, the property name doesn't transfer through to the child validator, so I get messages like:

```
  must be in the past
```

Where I expected "SentDateString" at the front of that. I haven't been able to figure out how to make that work. Is there an easy way? Am I doing the whole thing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be pretty easy, just needed to pass  in an `IRuleBuilderOptions` instead of an `IRuleBuilder` and then use `Configure` to copy over the display name.

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TFrom> Xform<T, TFrom, TTo>(
    this IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TFrom> ruleBuilder,
    Func<TFrom, TTo> xform,
    Func<IRuleBuilder<TFrom, TTo>, IRuleBuilderOptions<TFrom, TTo>> innerRules)
{
    var innerValidator = new InlineValidator<TFrom>() {
        v => innerRules(v.RuleFor(x => xform(x)))
                .Configure(c1 => ruleBuilder.Configure(c2 => c1.DisplayName = c2.DisplayName))
    };
    return ruleBuilder.SetValidator(innerValidator);
}
```